# Customize a dojo's ComboBox

Tags: css, dojo

How to add/replace some picture at the ▼ sign of *dijit.form.ComboBox* or *dijit.form.FilteringSelect*

and the picture can switch when mouse move in  and move out.

And how to change popup's bg-color of the ComboBox.

[Like this web site](http://logistics.nostramap.com/)

(I need to copy like the original from that site. But this site use a custom widget then I don't know how to get the source.)

If anyone know how to customize like that please teach me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the look and feel of Dojo widgets is done using themes.
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/themes.html

You can see the themes that ship by default at 
http://archive.dojotoolkit.org/nightly/dojotoolkit/dijit/themes/themeTester.html
(NOTE: This page is based on a nightly build, so soemtimes it is broken)

Themes are applied using CSS.
I'd create your own css style sheet.
Add the theme name to the body node.

```
<body class="tundra myTheme">
```

The particular css you are looking for is

```
.myTheme .dijitComboBox .dijitDownArrowButton {} /* The grey box */
.myTheme .dijitComboBox .dijitDownArrowButton .dijitArrowButtonInner { /* The arrow */
   background: url(images/spriteArrows.png) no-repeat scroll 0 center;
} 

/* Hover */
.myTheme .dijitComboBox .dijitDownArrowButtonHover {} /* The grey box */
.myTheme .dijitComboBox .dijitDownArrowButtonHover .dijitArrowButtonInner {} /* The arrow  */

/* Active (mouse down) */
.myTheme .dijitComboBox .dijitDownArrowButtonActive {} /* The grey box */
.myTheme .dijitComboBox .dijitDownArrowButtonActive .dijitArrowButtonInner {} /* The arrow */
```

Using the developer tools with your browser will help you determine the css classes that you are looking to override.

Comment: Thanks @Craig Swing, but I forgot to ask about how to switch the image when mouse move in and move out.

Comment: _And +1 to you for the new knowledge._

Comment: I updated the css to show the hover and active styles for a ComboBox.  The Dojo controls all use the same technique with hover and active.  There are other 'states' and you see more in the base mixin - dijit._CssStateMixin.

Answer (score 0):

I had looking at the code by closely then I found it's doesn't use *dijit.form.ComboBox* or *dijit.form.FilteringSelect*.

He used at normal HTML `<div>` `<input>`  `<a>`

Here http://jsfiddle.net/fQZFr/

I have finished.