# How can I replace the icons in a dijit Tree with font-awesome icons?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, font-awesome

I'm trying to switch out the icons in a dijit tree (specifically those that correspond with dijitFolderClosed, dijitFolderOpened - classes that apply to parent nodes in the tree) with font-awesome 'icons'. Switching out what icons are displayed is easy when the icons are actually image files - I can just change what class is returned by getIconClass().

However, font-awesome seems to work through inserting pseudoelements, and I'm having trouble getting this to work with dijit. The icon nodes are `img` elements, and while some approach like [this](http://davidwalsh.name/font-awesome-tags) looks promising, but doesn't work on `img` tags because they don't have `content` attributes.

What are some good options for getting font-awesome to work as dijit tree icons? It looks possible to mess with the `img` tags as [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843035/does-before-not-work-on-img-elements) suggest, or I could use replaceChild() to replace the `img` icon elements with elements that font-awesome can apply to. Can anyone think of better solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override your dijit styles: set `background-image: none` on .dijitIcon*  and `display:none` on .dijit*Inner classes, then put FontAwesome content in before pseudo classes.

I've done this using Sass on many dijits, [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stafamus/yon52g5b/) is an example for dijit/form/ComboBox. The key bits are:

```
     .dijitDownArrowButton {
         &:before {
             font-family:'FontAwesome';
             content: '\f0d7';
         }
         .dijitArrowButtonContainer {
             background-image: none;
         }
         .dijitArrowButtonInner {
             display: none;
         }
    }
```

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10088328/1759693) explains overriding dijit classes well. And dijit theme overriding tutorial is [here](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/themes.html).